# Convergence of a product of two infinite sums

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $(\theta_j)_{j \in \mathbb{Z}}$ and $(\phi_j)_{j \in \mathbb{Z}}$ be two collections of real numbers indexed by integers.

I am asked to show that
$$\sum_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}\sum_{j \in \mathbb{Z}}\lvert \theta_j\phi_i\rvert \leq \sum_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}\lvert\phi_i\rvert\sum_{j \in \mathbb{Z}}\lvert \theta_j\rvert\tag{1}$$

What I don't understand is how this is not an obvious equality. I would get it if the expression were
$$\sum_{j \in \mathbb{Z}}\lvert \theta_j\phi_j\rvert \leq \sum_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}\lvert\phi_i\rvert\sum_{j \in \mathbb{Z}}\lvert \theta_j\rvert$$
since then there is a possibility that the two collections, $(\theta_j)_{j \in \mathbb{Z}}$ and $(\phi_j)_{j \in \mathbb{Z}}$, cancel each other out when multiplied.

Can someone show why an inequality is needed in $(1)$?

Comment: No. You can safely replace $\leq$ with $=$ in $(1)$.

Comment: If you placed correctly the absolute values in (1), this is indeed an identity.